# killer n1525 with ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, 14.10

fresh stock setup of ubuntu 14.10 on a gs70 with killer n1525 wifi. 
lspci shows both, but wifi seems not recognized correct:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 003e (rev 20)
```

anyone managed to get the killer n1525 wifi working?

thanx a lot...

Comment: What is the specific problem you are encountering? Do you get an error message? Or are there no wifi networks listed in the networking menu?

Comment: no error message. but no wifi-device around. basically as here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184?comments=all

Answer (score 1):

**Update #2:** You shouldn't need the 4.1.0-wl-ath+ kernel fork anymore. My Wi-Fi works on a stock Linux 4.3.0 kernel. Ensure you're running kernel 4.3+ and your linux-fimware package contains the correct firmware files for your device

**UPDATE: Firmware now works!**

I've created a fork of the ath10k firmware repository on github and added the new firmware under `ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/`

See: https://github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware

The following is taken from laag's comment in the launchpad bug tracker and has detailed instructions on how to extract the firmware from the Windows driver (which I've done in the repo listed above) and compiling a new kernel in Ubuntu. **please note the `skip_otp=y` option for the ath10k_core module is required!**

```
I got it working as described in this thread: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/ath10k/2015-April/004958.html
Using xubuntu (14.10 upgraded to 15.04) Anyway distro shouldn't be much different. Basically to make it working you need to do (what i did):

1. Get the windows drivers from your notebook manufacturer, in my case MSI GS60. http://download.msi.com/nb_drivers/lan/KillerSuite_1.1.49.1068_Win7_Win81-MSI.zip
2. Get the needed phyton scripts to extract windows firmware:
dissect.py https://gist.github.com/kazikcz/8e5845ad84ca251aa295
assemble.py https://gist.github.com/kazikcz/c970cbf3a863ebbc4495
3. Get kvalo's kernel tree from https://github.com/kvalo/ath

4. Unpack Killer suite and run the following commands: (run commands as root , sudo / sudo su)
python dissect.py < drivers/Production/Windows8.1-x64/k1525w81/qca61x420.bin
mkdir /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
python assemble.py killer-n1525-fw 0 fw-2.bin fw-1.bin 4 > /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
cp drivers/Production/Windows8.1-x64/k1525w81/eeprom_qca9377_1p0_NFA435_olpc.bin /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin

5. Unpack kvalo's kernel and compile it with:

sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev gcc make git exuberant-ctags

To simplify things copy your current kernel config to ath-master root folder:
cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config
you can configure if you want with: (not needed)
make menuconfig
then compile with: (where X is the number of cores of you processor, i used 6)
make -jX
# then take a coffee or even better a cold beer, anyway it just took about 20 minutes for me.

6. Install the new kernel:
sudo make modules_install install

7. Create config file with:
nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf
Write to it:
options ath10k_core skip_otp=y

8. Reboot using your new kernel 4.x.x-wl-ath

9. Run ifconfig

10. Voila wlan0 should be there waiting for you, now try to connect to you AP.

If its not working try to check if you missed something, check log file (/var/log/dmesg) for more details of what failed.

Give thanks to the guys who made this possible for me: http://lists.infradead.org/mailman/listinfo/ath10k
```

I followed the steps and it worked fine on my MSI WS-60. You can see my comment at the bottom (#122) for more details:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

Comment: This works great on my Kali 2.0 install, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off; I'm a total Linux noob. Please forgive me if I use wrong terminology or words but I did get the QCA6174 Killer 1525 to work on my laptop much easier than all of the above answers; or the ones I found elsewhere. All information I found is from 2014 and I guess most people will know how to easily fix it but for those users like me; here is what I did.

I followed KillerNetworking their official support information (which involved compiling an entire new kernel) which 1) did not work and 2) is an out-dated, overcomplicated method (as a new user it took me 3hrs to understand and in the end didn't do anything).

So here comes the solution that got my QCA6174 1525 to work on a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10:

- Download this zip: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/
- Extract the .ZIP file
- Go to the extracted files and locate two .bin files here:

  /ath10k-firmware-master/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1
- Here you find two files: - `board.bin` and `firmware-5.bin` First create a new folder for these two driver files. Use this command:

`sudo mkdir lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1`

- Now the new folder is made, copy the two driver files there:

`sudo cp /ath10k-firmware-master/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/{board.bin,firmware-5.bin} /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1`

- Navigate to the new location `cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1` and confirm there the two `.bin` files are there.

Restart your machine and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2248919&highlight=n1525 I know of no method to get this device working at this time. I suggest you add to the referenced bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The proper support in the ath10k driver should have just been added with the Linux kernel 4.0 (ex 3.20).

I still have not tested it but this seems pretty clear according to:

> News:
>
> 2015-01-27 QCA6174 support added, will be in 3.20.

here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k

Note that the QCA6174 is the chip mounted in the n1525, see: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Qualcomm_Atheros_Killer_Wireless-AC_1525

So just upgrade to the latest Linux kernel.

Comment: Support is in the kernel, but we still need the firmware image that needs to be loaded during driver initialization (see my answer)